# JSON parsing empty display

Tags: android

How should I parse that JSON http://rutube.ru/api/video/editors/?page=1&format=json? I've got empty display. I take example from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

JSONPARSER.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);   
        int httpStatus = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (httpStatus != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

        }       
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jObj;
    }
 }
```

MAINACTIVITY.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private static String URL_VIDEO = "http";
private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
private static final String VIDEO_OBJECT = "video";
private static final String VIDEO_ID = "id";
private static final String VIDEO_TITLE = "title";
private static final String VIDEO_CREATED_TS = "created_ts";

JSONArray results = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_VIDEO);
        try {               
            results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = results.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject video = c.getJSONObject(VIDEO_OBJECT);
            String id = video.getString(VIDEO_ID);
            String title = video.getString(VIDEO_TITLE);
            String created_ts = video.getString(VIDEO_CREATED_TS);
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(VIDEO_ID, id);
            map.put(VIDEO_TITLE, title);
            map.put(VIDEO_CREATED_TS, created_ts);              
            resultList.add(map);
        }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, resultList, 
                R.layout.list_video_item, 
                new String[] { VIDEO_OBJECT, VIDEO_TITLE, VIDEO_CREATED_TS }, new int[] { R.id.object, R.id.title, R.id.created_ts });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();
    }
 }
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [Parsing JSON android, help need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154777/parsing-json-android-help-need)

Comment: delete pervoius post.

Answer (score 1):

Using [gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from Google its very simple:

```
String json = getJSONFromUrl(URL);// get json from internet as usual
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class); // let gson handle all the parsing and create Java objects
```

Where `Data` class is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_W4-wQ5QqD9U2RFN2ZiZzFRalE/edit?usp=sharing) generated using [this](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/) website.
I have never done manual json parsing like you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

That's prolly because the `URL_VIDEO` you're passing as an argument contains only `http`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something failed during the server communication, you should check the servers responsecode before reading the content.
Add this code after your `httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

```
int httpStatus = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
switch( httpStatus )
{ 
  case HttpStatus.SC_OK:
  {
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent(); 
    // Continue with reading the content here
  }
  default:
  {   
    // here you can print errormessages or information what happened 
  }
}
```

The full code for your class could be:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);   
        int httpStatus = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        switch( httpStatus )
        { 
          case HttpStatus.SC_OK:
          {
            try {
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
          }       
          break;
        }
        default:
        {   
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "HttpStatus: "+httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ", message: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()  );
          jObj = null;
        }
      }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jObj;
    }
 }
```

This should help you to see what the server is responding, hope I didn`t forget a { in the code ;)
The 'default' of the switch is your error section, for every server response except`200 OK` you will get a log entry with the server response.

If you need more cases (e.g. is you like different messages for `403 Forbidden` Yust add more `case HttpStatus.SC_XXXXX` blocks.
Check wiki if you need more informations about [Http Statuscodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: I have alreay posted the full code of JSonParser class, what do you need ? Do you nee the code of the main activity to ??

Comment: I do not need anymore, i did it myself!